Database clearing even when I don't want it to
As part of a program I'm making in VB.NET forms, there's the option to delete the contents of a database. This functionality isn't intended to be used very often in the final version and I wouldn't want users to accidentally click on the button and delete the contents when they didn't want to.
I didn't think a simple message box with Yes and No buttons would cut it, as I've heard of several people doing things in programs they didn't want to even with measures like these in place. So, I wanted the message box that pops up to have a "no" button and a checkbox which needs to be ticked to reveal the "yes" button. However, there exists no default message box that has this. After further research, I decided to create a custom one. It works for the most part, however, it clears the database anyway, regardless of whether I tick the checkbox and press "yes" or whether I press "no".
Below is the code that is used to clear the database:
Private Sub btnClearDatabase_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearDatabase.Click
    'Opens the Clear Database dialog to confirm if the user wants to clear the database.
    ClearDatabase.ShowDialog()
    If ClearDatabase.DialogResult.OK Then
        'Clears Database. Code not shown
    End If
End Sub

I set the DialogResult property of the "yes" button to OK, so I assumed that the code in the If statement would only run if that button was pressed. But it runs anyway regardless if I press it. It runs when I open the dialog. Why does it do this?
It might have something to do with a warning in the If statement code that says:

BC42025 Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Rewriting If ClearDatabase.DialogResult.OK Then as If DialogResult.Ok Then gets rid of the warning but running it still has the same result. I'm really confused as to why it's doing this.
EDIT: To clarify, the code doesn't run the moment the dialog opens. It runs the moment the dialog closes.

It would be safer to have a text box in addition to the OK/Cancel buttons, where the user must type in "delete" to unlock the OK button.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes or even something more substantial; a web app that I use frequently requires the user to type things like "I am certain" in order to approve potentially dangerous actions.

Create a separate executable that only deletes the data. Don't have that option as part of the main program. The separate executable could have one form and prompt the user to confirm (preferably in the manner @OlivierJacot-Descombes describes).

For this sort of thing I've sometimes used an InputBox to ask for a confirmation phrase

This is wrong:
If ClearDatabase.DialogResult.OK Then

All you're doing is converting a constant value to a Boolean and checking whether it's True. That value is never zero so of course it will be True. That code should be like this:
If ClearDatabase.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then

Even better, change this:
ClearDatabase.ShowDialog()
If ClearDatabase.DialogResult.OK Then

to this:
If ClearDatabase.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

The fact that the code you have compiled shows that you must have Option Strict Off, which is bad. If you had it On then the code would not have compiled and you'd have known there was an issue there. Turn Option Strict On in the project properties and also in the VS options dialogue, so it will be On by default in future projects.

If ClearDatabase.DialogResult = DIalogResult.OK Then did not fix the problem but If ClearDatabase.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then did. Also, thanks for suggesting to turn Option Strict On I was completely oblivious to the fact that that option existed. Thanks for the help.

@JamesGilbert are you setting the ClearDatabase form's DialogResult properly? Why don't you post the code of your custom dialog form.

I would try to do two separate buttons for clearing or just having a clear button option. I'm having a little trouble trying to figure out the error without the full code but I do believe it is telling you that the if statement (to clear or not clear the database), will be skipped and you will be clearing either way.
